# Iionic/Angular: Смена вида в контроллере || Partial

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Не знал как назвать тему, вроде отражает что нужно.

Все было прекрасно, пока не дошел до построение отчетов в своем приложении.
Отчет - это не пользователи или другие однородные сущности, у него свой набор данных, свой внешний вид.
Для каждого отчета нужна своя вьюха.

Пока пришел к решению, что нужно для каждого отчета свое объявление через  state.
Но это может раздуть, при наличии от 10 отчетов, секцию .config(), если правильно выразился.

Хочется реализовать это все через switch в контроллере, использовать что то вроде партиций из Zend.
Надеюсь получилось отразить что нужно.
Если неясно выразился, спрашивайте, дополню.

Благодарю.

Comment: Так в чем собственно вопрос то?

Comment: Хочется реализовать это все через switch в контроллере, использовать что то вроде партиций из Zend. Вопрос - Как? Стоит явно написать?

Comment: если просто загрузить разметку - `ng-include` в помощь

Comment: стейты можно параметризовать, тогда понадобится всего один стейт с параметром, в зависимости от которого подгружать нужную разметку

Comment: Оформите в виде ответа, если не сложно. Я пока реализовал через модальные окна на всю страницы с кнопкой "закрыть" как "назад".